# Twoway multibinding validation

Tags: validation, multibinding, two-way-binding

I have this case where there is a multibinding for ex,
textbox1 which value depend on textbox2 and textbox3 and the binding is two way,
all textbox applied the same validation rule for ex error if minus.

somehow if textbox1 got updated the textbox2 and textbox3 validation will fire.
but when either textbox2 or textbox3 updated, textbox1 validation will not fire.

- I have tried set the ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" but nothing happened.

Any advice?

Comment: You haven't said what language or framework you're using. Also, you should post relevant code. It makes it easier to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that ValidatesOnTargetUpdated is not observed by Multibinding